# Get the lastest entry for a certain item? Mysql

Tags: mysql, search

Lets say I have a table with 2 columns, 1 contains Cars and 1 contains random numbers.
How can I search for the lastest "ferrari" entry in the table and know whats the random number for that ferrari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your Cars table has columns `id`, `name`,`rnid`

You can use following sql;

```
SELECT MAX(c.id) AS latestferrari FROM Cars c INNER JOIN randomnumbers rn ON c.rnid=rn.id WHERE c.name="ferrari"
```